# Can't assign jQuery jqModal to dynamically added links

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqmodal

I've been having problems getting jqmodal modal dialogs to display on links added dynamically by client side code.  I've demonstrated the problem at the following URL: http://www.neil-burton.co.uk/jqmodaltest/index.htm

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Neil, updated my answer. Make sure your using the latest jqModal version.

Comment: Can you try passing in this to the jqmShow function. I kind of got it working here http://pastebin.me/0d90eb8f215da8867f0ad1161bcf5433

Comment: I am using the latest version, which is R14.  Not sure if that dev version is current though.  This seems to work.  I've applied it to the test code and it's having the desire effect :)  I'll go away and apply it to my live code and see if it works there too.  I'll comment when I've done this.  Thanks very much.

Comment: No worries, good luck with it

Comment: Everything working correctly on our live site now.  Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) for the anchor click events

**UPDATED AGAIN**

```
  $('#dialog').jqm({ajax:'@rel'});

  // open the modal whenever anchor links on the page are clicked
  $('a.someClass').live('click',function(){
      $('#dialog').jqmShow(this);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help redsquare.  In my live example I need to populate the modal dialog with content via ajax.  The URL for the ajax is taken from the rel attribute of the triggering link.   That link is dynamically generated by the server, so the links look like this:

<a class="addnotetrigger" href="#" rel="ajax.asp?id=1">Link</a>
<a class="addnotetrigger" href="#" rel="ajax.asp?id=2">Link</a>

Comment: The dialog is blank because @rel has no reference I'm guessing.  If I replace @rel with ajax.htm, then the script works so far as any new links cause the modal dialog to appear when clicked. I need to be able to set the ajax property from the rel attribute of each link.

Comment: ahh. The plugin writer does not provide an un-obfuscated version of his code. It is a nightmare to debug.....My advice would be to look for a decent plugin!

Comment: Thanks again for your help on this.  I'm annoyed with myself.  I've done quite a lot of work utilising this plugin, only to come up against this problem towards the end of my project. It's unfortunate the developer doesn't follow normal jQuery plugin creation conventions providing an un-obfuscated version of his code. I also tried to pick my way through it and it's not easy! It's a great plugin otherwise.